# sqlalchemy how to use metadata to build query

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I can get my column names by doing

```
for c in models.User.__table__.column:
 c.name
```

Now supposed I did the following:

```
users=models.User.query.all()
user=users[0]

for c in models.User.__table__.column:
 print(user.c.name)
```

The user.c.name is the problem. c.name is a string of the column name ie 'id', 'username', 'password'. So instead of tying user.id I could have user[c.name]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get? users, with name `bob`?

Comment: I am trying to pull data from columns based on metadata. I'll update the template to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do, as it doesn't seem very conventional. Might the following be what you're looking for?

```
user = models.User.query.first()

for c in models.User.__table__.columns:
    print( getattr(user, c.name) )
```

Comment: Almost, I reworded the question to make it more applicable to what I am doing.

Comment: modified my answer... any closer?

Comment: Perfect! I'll add this as the answer if you can edit column to columns, that's what made it work for me.

Comment: I tried to edit __table__.column to __table__.columns and it wouldn't let me saying edits have to be at least 6 characters so I went ahead and accepted your answer, thanks a bunch for the help.

Comment: Fixed to `columns`. Glad I can help!